# CoreNLP: why is the output result containing only separate letters rather than separate words?

Tags: stanford-nlp, tokenize

I'm a beginner in programming, and I was trying to use coreNLP to perform tokenization to movie subtitles.

I already extracted all the sentences from subtitle files and made it into a .txt file which looks like this:

```
It's another hot and sunny
The temperature in downtown
And at night will drop to...
I think about that day
I left him at the Greyhound station
West of Santa Fe
We were 17 but he was sweet and it was true
Still I did what I had to do
Cause I just knew
...
```

The command I ran was

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx500m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize -outputFormat text -file La.La.Land.2016.DVDScr.XVID.AC3.HQ.Hive-CM8.txt
```

I was expecting the output to be seperate tokens, however, the output contained only seperate letters, which is something like:

```
[Text=I CharacterOffsetBegin=2 CharacterOffsetEnd=3]
[Text=t CharacterOffsetBegin=4 CharacterOffsetEnd=5]
[Text=' CharacterOffsetBegin=6 CharacterOffsetEnd=7]
[Text=s CharacterOffsetBegin=8 CharacterOffsetEnd=9]
[Text=a CharacterOffsetBegin=12 CharacterOffsetEnd=13]
[Text=n CharacterOffsetBegin=14 CharacterOffsetEnd=15]
[Text=o CharacterOffsetBegin=16 CharacterOffsetEnd=17]
...
```

Since I'm fairly new to programming and coreNLP, I can't seem to find a way to solve this issue, as other sample input.txt seems to work just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks a lot like you have a hidden character in between each character -- look at the character offset fields. Perhaps one of the funky unicode zero-width space ones? What happens if you put a portion the file through a hex editor (e.g., https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/)? I wager you'll see one of the characters described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) before each regular character.

Comment: @Gabor Angeli Thanks! This is exactly the problem, thank you for the help!